# C# Wait for part of while loop to finish to execute another action

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert one value to another. I am importing a text file, using streamreader/writer. I want to know if I can have the part of the while loop inside the if statement wait until the the rest of the loop finishes before writing what its supposed to. I know this is probably an easy question but for some reason I can put my finger on it. I am not using multithread processing and want to stay away from asynch.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(convertInput))
{
    string line;
    writer.WriteLine(formatter, "Original Value", "Converted Value");
    writer.WriteLine(formatter, "--------------", "---------------");
A:  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
            string str2BeConverted = line;
            long numHexToDex;
            if ((Int64.TryParse(line, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out numHexToDec)) == false)
            {
                    writer.WriteLine();
                    writer.Write(line + " " + "is not a Hexadecimal value.");
                    goto A;
            }

            Int64.TryParse(line, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out numHexToDec);
            string lineChanged = numHexToDec.ToString("G");
    }
}
```

I am wanting to wait until all the values that parse successfully are written, then write the ones that didn't at the end.

Comment: What's the "false part of the while loop"? After all, it's not an if statement... If you mean the code right after the closing brace of the while loop, then it's going to "wait" for the loop to complete: that's the way loops work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "false values" and "true values". If you mean "the condition of the while loop", then there's only one "false value" -- when the stream is empty and the loop will end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to write these to some sort of buffer instead, such as a StringBuilder, and then write the StringBuilder's contents out after all the successful elements were processed:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(convertInput))
{
    string line;
    Stringbuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    writer.WriteLine(formatter, "Original Value", "Converted Value");
    writer.WriteLine(formatter, "--------------", "---------------");
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
            string str2BeConverted = line;
            long numHexToDex;
            if ((Int64.TryParse(line, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out numHexToDec)) == false)
            {

                    builder.AppendLine();
                    builder.Append(line + " " + "is not a Hexadecimal value.");
                    continue; //there is ALWAYS an alternative to goto
            }

            Int64.TryParse(line, NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out numHexToDec);
            string lineChanged = numHexToDec.ToString("G");
    }

    writer.Write(builder.ToString();
}
```

Also, as many comments have stated, code that uses `goto` is NEVER good code. There is ALWAYS something else you could do that is more correct, and in this case it's extremely simple (the `continue` keyword will bypass the rest of the loop block, re-evaluate the while condition, and iterate further if indicated).

Comment: Thanks KeithS I am learning c# still and didnt think about the StringBuilder. and for the goto's, I had gotten that mixed up with break for some reason, have no idea why.